# DevExpress RibbonControl page author

Tags: c#, devexpress, ribbon-control

I want to authorize according to the user logged into the pages on the RibbonControl. For example, the user whose role is "Admin" should not see the page with "STOK". How can I do it ?

[image]

Comment: Why on earth do you keep changing the edit?

Comment: Do it in runtime, not in design. Set the Visibility property of STOK to Always or Never.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [RibbonPage.Visible](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonPage.Visible) property to hide the page at runtime or design time. Hidden pages can be made visible again only in code.
If a page belongs to a custom category, you can hide all pages in this category by setting the [RibbonPageCategory.Visible](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonPageCategory.Visible) property to false.

To learn more, take a look at the [Navigating Pages and Controling Page Visibility](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2494/controls-and-libraries/ribbon-bars-and-menu/ribbon/visual-elements/ribbon-page#navigating-pages-and-controling-page-visibility) help article.